# JavaScript Bundle getting build every time it finish building. Expo XDE

Tags: expo

Hope you guys can help me with this weird issue I'm facing.
The app bundle is getting build everything time it finishes building. So its like once it gets to 100% it starts all over again. One thing I made to kind of solve it, is to enable the "Remote debugging" option on the expo App. But that will only work for a minute and will start the loop of building the bundle again.
I have also reinstalled the node_modules & cleaned expo cache but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I'm facing the same issue right now. I just created a project with the `create-react-native-app` command and copy dependencies from another project into the `package.json` of the new project. I ran `npm install` and `npm start`. That's all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I found it. It was because of iCloud Drive on MAC. For some reason that I don't understand (since it did not happen before under the same conditions) the refresh of the files is forced.

So move your app folder to another place that is not on iCloud Drive and it will work.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Oh my gosh. I spent 2 days trying to figure out, what's going on there.

Answer (score 3):

It was Dropbox sync causing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you shouldn’t need to rebuild your APK on every change, you should only need to run exp publish to see your updated app show up in your existing APK. If you change anything in app.json you’ll need to run the build again, but if you aren’t touching app.json then you should be mostly fine to just publish and not run a standalone build.